Excessive White Space at the Bottom in iOS with SafeAreaView and KeyboardAvoidingView
I'm encountering an issue with excessive white space at the bottom of the screen in iOS while using SafeAreaView, KeyboardAvoidingView, and ScrollView. The layout works fine on Android, but on iOS, there's an unwanted blank area below the content.
Here’s my current implementation of the component:
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import {
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  RefreshControl,
  Platform,
} from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

const MainView = ({
  style,
  children,
  fixedHeader,
  loading,
  hasRefresh = false,
  refreshing = false,
  onRefresh,
  onScroll,
  needScrollView = true,
  needTopEdge = true,
  theme,
  insets,
}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={[
        styles.safeAreaView,
        style,
        { paddingBottom: insets.bottom, marginBottom: 0 }, // Adjusting padding
      ]}
      edges={
        needTopEdge ? ["bottom", "left", "right", "top"] : ["bottom", "left", "right"]
      }
    >
      {fixedHeader}
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : undefined}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={insets.top + 10} // Setting offset
      >
        {needScrollView ? (
          <ScrollView
            onScroll={onScroll}
            automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets={true}
            contentContainerStyle={[
              styles.scrollViewContent,
              { paddingBottom: insets.bottom }, // Adding bottom padding
            ]}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            refreshControl={
              hasRefresh ? (
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
              ) : undefined
            }
          >
            {loading ? <ThemedActiveIndicator /> : children}
          </ScrollView>
        ) : (
          <>{loading ? <ThemedActiveIndicator /> : children}</>
        )}
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <StatusBar
        style={theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"}
        backgroundColor={"black"}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = {
  safeAreaView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  scrollViewContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingBottom: 20, // Adding padding
  },
};

export default MainView;

#Getting same white space issue wit this code also
import { SafeAreaView, useSafeAreaInsets } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, RefreshControl, NativeSyntheticEvent, NativeScrollEvent } from "react-native";
import { StyleProps } from "react-native-reanimated";
import { ThemedView } from "@/components/ThemedView";
import { useGlobalContext } from "@/context/GlobalProvider";
import ThemedActiveIndicator from "../themedActiveIndicator/ThemedActiveIndicator";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  style?: StyleProps;
  needTopEdge?: boolean;
  hasRefresh?: boolean;
  refreshing?: boolean;
  onRefresh?: () => void;
  fixedHeader?: ReactNode;
  onScroll?: (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => void;
  loading?:boolean;
  needScrollView?:boolean;
  addBottomMargin?:boolean;
}

const MainView = ({
  children,
  style,
  needTopEdge = false,
  hasRefresh = false,
  refreshing = false,
  loading=false,
  fixedHeader,
  onScroll,
  onRefresh = () => {},
  needScrollView=true,
  addBottomMargin=false
}: Props) => {
  const { theme } = useGlobalContext();
  const inserts = useSafeAreaInsets()
  return (
    <ThemedView style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={[
          styles.safeAreaView,
          style,
          addBottomMargin ? { marginBottom: inserts.top +60 } : {},
        ]}
        edges={
          needTopEdge
            ? ["bottom", "left", "right", "top"]
            : ["bottom", "left", "right"]
        }
      >
        {fixedHeader}
        {needScrollView ? (
          <ScrollView
            onScroll={onScroll}
            automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets={true}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            refreshControl={
              hasRefresh ? (
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
              ) : undefined
            }
          >
            {loading ? <ThemedActiveIndicator /> : children}
          </ScrollView>
        ) : (
          <>{loading ? <ThemedActiveIndicator /> : children}</>
        )}

        <StatusBar
          style={theme == "dark" ? "light" : "dark"}
          backgroundColor={"black"}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ThemedView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaView: { flex: 1, padding: 0, margin: 0 },
  keyboardAvoidingView: { flex: 1 },
  scrollViewContent: { flexGrow: 1 },
});

export default React.memo(MainView);


The Problem:
On iOS:

A large amount of white space appears at the bottom of the screen, particularly when the keyboard is dismissed.

What I’ve tried so far:

Adjusting keyboardVerticalOffset in KeyboardAvoidingView.
Adding/removing paddingBottom in contentContainerStyle of ScrollView.
Ensuring flexGrow: 1 is applied only where necessary.
Debugging with console.log(insets.bottom) to ensure safe area insets are calculated correctly.


Questions:

Why is this white space appearing specifically on iOS?
Is there a better approach to combining SafeAreaView, KeyboardAvoidingView, and ScrollView to avoid this issue?
Are there any platform-specific quirks or alternatives I should consider?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! 

does it space at the bottom visible when the screen is initialized? or after you dismiss keyboard?.

Here's a solution to your problem to apply padding on based on platform.
const styles = {
  safeAreaView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  scrollViewContent: {
    flexGrow: 1, //removed paddingBottom from here.
  },
};

Add platform check like this:
 <ScrollView
            onScroll={onScroll}
            automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets={true}
            contentContainerStyle={[
              styles.scrollViewContent,
              { paddingBottom: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 20 : insets.bottom}, // padding according to OS.
            ]}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            refreshControl={
              hasRefresh ? (
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
              ) : undefined
            }
          >

